# Malformed generated report in Docx format

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm trying to export a docx file through JRDocxExporter. The trouble is that when i try to print this generated document, I get an error about the page margin. I saw that this exporter is not able to set the margin of a word document.

I'm exporting the document in this way:

```
JasperReport reportCompiled = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(pathJrxmlFile);
JasperPrint  reportFilled = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportCompiled, null, dataSource);

JRDocxExporter exp = new JRDocxExporter();

exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,pathFile);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT,reportFilled);
exporter.exportReport();
```

I'm using *JasperReports 5.0.0* and *iReport 5.1.0*. Then when i try to print the document generated from *MS Word* i get this message:

[image]

Can somebody help me?

Comment: `I get an error about the page margin` - What error? `I saw that this exporter is not able to set the margin of a word document.` - What do you mean?

Comment: When I try to print, I get that the margins of Section 1 are outside the printable area. But on IReport I set the margin of the document.

Comment: Can you add the screenshot? What exporter are you using in *iReport*? What versions of *JasperReports API* and *iReport* are you using?

Comment: I'm using JasperReport 5.0.0 and IReport 5.1.0. Then when i try to print the document generated from word i get this message: [screenshot] (http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/8014/x98j.png)

Comment: Can you post the *jrxml* file?

Comment: This is the  [file](http://www.4shared.com/file/agHaIIiU/report__1_.html)

Comment: Can you post (insert) file to your question?

Comment: I don't understand, what do I do? I already attached the jrxml file

Comment: I have not access to this file. You can copy & paste the text of *jrxml* file to your question in Edit mode.

Comment: Try from this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tbaw92vxwnmx5ua/report%20%281%29.jrxml)

Answer (score 0):

I found that this kind of problem is a bug, and has been already reported.

[Margins cause warning when printing docx in Word](http://community.jaspersoft.com/ireport-designer/issues/5815)